# What is the exact order of __init__ invocation in inheritance in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, inheritance

Regarding the three classes defined below, what is the order for Python interpreter to reach line 1,line 2 and line 3.

```py
class GranParent():
    def __init__(self):
        #line 1
class Parent(GrandParent):
    def  __init__(self):
        #line 2
        super().__init__()
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        #line 3
ob = Child()
```

a) line 3, line 2, line 1
b) line 2, line 3, line 1
c) line 2, line 1, line 3
d) line 1, line 2, line 3
e) line 1, line 3, line 2
f) None of the above

My initial guess was d) since  the Class child inherits from the Parent's Class which inherits from the Grandparent Class,  but the answer key says the answer is C. I have no idea why it is C.

Comment: `Parent` executes `#line 2` *before* calling `GrandParent.__init__()`, so #2 has to be before #1.  And `Child` then executes `#line 3` after all that happens.

Comment: Don't guess: `Child.__mro__` will *tell* you the order. The question, though, isn't just about the order in which `__init__` is called, but the order of the lines *in* each definition of `__init__`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever it reaches `super().__init__()` line, it stops at that point in the current frame and go and run the new initializer frame.

In `Child`, `super().__init__()` is before `#line 3`, so it jumps to `Parent`'s `__init__`. First it runs `#line 2`, **then** it reaches to the `super().__init__()` line and again jumps to `GrandParent`'s `__init__` and run `#line 1`.

After `GrandParent`'s `__init__` finishes, it comes back and continue the previous frame which is `Parent`'s `__init__`, but there is nothing to execute there. It comes back once more to `Chils`'s `__init__` and finally executes `#line 3`.